# Show an uploaded image in PHP

Tags: php, html, xampp

This is my first post, so please tell me if theres anything that I have done wrong with this post.

I am currently doing a school task with three subtasks.

1) Make an HTML form with the possibility to upload an image
2) Save the data from the HTML form in a text document and place the image on the server
3) Make a page where the different entries shows up (including the image).

Heres is what I have done so far. Task 1 should be pretty correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<html>
<head>

    <title>Mobiloversigten</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

    <form name="formular" id="formular" method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on">

        <fieldset>

            <legend>Enhedsoplysninger</legend>
            <div><label>Producent: <input type="text" name="manufactor" id="manufactor" required="required" size="30"></label></div>
            <div><label>Produktnavn: <input type="text" name="product" id="product" required="required" size="30"></label></div>
            <div><label>Farve: <input type="text" name="color" id="color" required="required" size="30"></label></div>
            <label>Hukommelse:
                <div>    
                    <select size="1" name="memory" id="memory">
                        <option>8GB</option>
                        <option>16GB</option>
                        <option>32GB</option>
                        <option>64GB</option>
                        <option>128GB</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </label>
            <div><label>Skærmstørrelse <input type="number" name="displaysize" id="displaysize" min="0" step="0.1" size="30"></label></div>   
            <div><label>Produktbillede: <input type="file" name="productphoto" id="productphoto" required="required" size="30"></label></div>

        </fieldset>

        <div><input type="submit" id="ok" value="Indsend"><input type="reset" id="nulstil" value="Nulstil"></div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

My process.php page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<html>
<head>

    <title>Mobiloversigten</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

<a href="index.html">Tilføj flere enheder</a>
<a href="overview.php">Vis enheder</a>


<?php

$manufactor = $_POST['manufactor'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$memory = $_POST['memory'];
$displaysize = $_POST['displaysize'];
$productphoto = $_FILES['productphoto']['name'];


if($_FILES){

            if(strlen($_FILES['productphoto']['type'])==9){

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productphoto']['tmp_name'], $product . ".".$rest = substr($_FILES['productphoto']['type'], -3));
            }
            else{move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productphoto']['tmp_name'], $product . ".".$rest = substr($_FILES['productphoto']['type'], -4));

            }
            }

    $user_data = "$manufactor, $product, $color, $memory, $displaysize, $productphoto \r\n";
    $mobile_data = "Producent: ,Produktnavn: ,Farve: ,Hukommelse: ,Skærmstørrelse: ";

    $fh = fopen("data.txt", "a+")   or die("Filen kunne ikke oprettes");
    fwrite($fh, $user_data)         or die("Kunne ikke skrive til filen");
    fclose($fh);

    $fj = fopen("mobile.txt", "w")  or die("Filen kunne ikke oprettes");
    fwrite($fj, $mobile_data)       or die("Kunne ikke skrive til filen");
    fclose($fj);

?>

</body>

</html>
```

The page which shows the overview of all entries looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<html>
<head>
<title>Mobiloversigt</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1>Tilføjede enheder</h1>
<?php

    fopen("file.txt", "r");
    fopen("mobil.txt", "r");
    $info = explode(",", file_get_contents("mobil.txt"));
    $retrieved_string = file_get_contents("file.txt");

    $retrieved_array = explode("\n", $retrieved_string);

    $count=count($retrieved_array)-1;

for($y = 0; $y < $count; $y++){
$user_data_array = explode(",",$retrieved_array[$y]);
    for($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++){
            echo "<p>$info[$x]</p><p2>$user_data_array[$x]</p2><br>";
}               echo "<img src=\"$user_data_array[5]\"><br><br>";
            echo "<div><span class=\"linie\"></span></div><br><br>";
}


?>        
</body>
</html>
```

The overall problem is, that the pictures don't show up. I see them in my root folder with the .php files and the index. file, but my browser just shows a blue question mark (Safari), so it seems like it doesn't recognize the image location, even though I can see it in the folder.

I would really appreciate some help! :-)

Thanks in advance

/Chris

Comment: You are looking at 'file.txt' while you are storing data at 'data.txt'

Comment: If you use Chrome, Press F12, go to the network tab, and refresh te page. Is the URL the image points to the right URL? (As in your file system)

Comment: wrong path to the file..

Comment: use `var_dump($user_data_array[5])` to check the path, this is likely wrong.

Comment: Even if you look at the corret file(data.txt), you will find '$_FILES['productphoto']['name']' as filename, but you save the file with the name '$product . ".".$rest = substr($_FILES['productphoto']['type'], -4)' with the move_uploaded_file function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: HI.. is the image path correct ?? Once check it..

Comment: Using Google Chrome I can see, that I'm looking for the wrong filename as @jolmos points!
So how do I make it look for the correct filename that I rename earlier in my code? I'm very new to PHP so I need to get it all basic.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in process.php the main error is that you are saving the photo with different name and printing tmp_name is file. In acutal both should be same required. Change the code little bit

```
 if($_FILES){
       if(strlen($_FILES['productphoto']['type'])==9)
            $name=$product . ".".$rest = substr($_FILES['productphoto']['type'], -3);
       else
            $name=$product . ".".$rest = substr($_FILES['productphoto']['type'], -4);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productphoto']['tmp_name'], $name);

 }

 $user_data = "$manufactor, $product, $color, $memory, $displaysize, $name \r\n";
```

In overview.php, fopen is not required if you are using file_get_contents thus delete the fopen line and second error correct the input file names as you are saving data in **data.txt** and **mobile.txt** but importing data from **mobil.txt** and **file.txt**. else every thing is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help.